# Is there any rm log with removed files?

Tags: logging, rm, administration

Is there any way to check what was recently removed with `rm` command?

Comment: Sorry, no. You may use harddisk recovering tools, if needed, but there are no logs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Some different solutions

There is no log, but if you want...

### Watch for deleted entries and log

You may use `inotify` libraries in *recursive* and *monitor* mode:

```
inotifywait -e delete --timefmt %c --format '%T %_e %w %f' -r -m / >/path/logfile
Setting up watches.  Beware: since -r was given, this may take a while!
Watches established.
Fri Jul 19 11:57:39 2013 DELETE /tmp/ testfiletodelete
Fri Jul 19 11:57:46 2013 DELETE /home/user/ testfiletodelete
```

This is a *sysadmin* approach: All user, all directories and mounted points...

**Warning** this could be a little *overkill* read carefully the man page and add some options like `--exclude`

### Patch [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) `rm` command

You could add something to your `.bashrc`...

#### Transform `rm`  from *delete* to *move to trash* command

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.Trashcan
rm() {
    local destdir=$(mktemp -d $HOME/.Trashcan/trash-XXXXXXXXX);
    mkdir $destdir/files
    echo $0 $@ >$destdir/command
    set >$destdir/environ
    mv -t $destdir/files $@
}
```

So every time you hit `rm` in your bash, files will be moved to a directory, command and environs will be saved too.

As each `rm` will create a new directory correctly dated, there is no need to use `date`.

#### Adding a log step to `rm` command.

But if you just wanna log your operation, at user lever:

```
rm() {
   date >>$HOME/.rm.log +"%a %d %b %Y %T: rm $@"
   /bin/rm $@
}
```

could do the job.

**Nota 1**

As @slhck rightly said: redefining usual commands may forge bad practice for new users, so if you modify such standards commands, your have to **not forget** this when you're working on another system!

**Nota 2**

This patch only `rm` command runned by interactive user shell. You may edit `/etc/bashrc` for making them for all users, but at all, only **bash** tools could be affected.

If files are removed by `unlink` in `perl` for sample, this will not be logged by this.

Or even if `ksh`, `dash` or else is invoked instead of bash... no logs.

**Nota 3**

For accessing original command,  instead of `alias` or personal `function`, you have to precise full path:  `/bin/rm myfile` will remove `myfile` but bypassing `rm` function, nothing will be logged.

Comment: But this doesn't actually delete your files, and it doesn't qute answer the question. When did those files get deleted?

Comment: @ssice Right, I've added another version of same principe.

Comment: Redefining builtins like `rm` is bad practice, because you'll get used to being safe when you're actually not—imagine working on another system that doesn't have this function. It's better to learn from those mistakes and type `rm -i` or similar whenever unsure, or list the files before deletion and then replace `ls` with `rm`.

Comment: @slhck ( `alias ls=rm` ? ... ;-)  Well, you're right, I agree: This *not real good idea* could have lather border effects... But this could help first steps of novice, mostly if this was added by himself. For myself, I use `alias ls="/bin/ls -ltrF --color --show-control-chars" la="ls -a"` and be never surprised when `ls` command don't give usual effect.

Comment: I think that there is no point in reinventing the wheel. See: `safe-rm` package (read more: [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/questions/337082/how-do-i-prevent-accidental-rm-rf), [launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/safe-rm), [Debian package](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=safe-rm)).

Answer (score 3):

If it is you who accidentally removed files, and your shell supports history, you can list the history back like this:

```
history | grep rm
```

Of course, you'll need to do an insight search through the history to know *where* you deleted the file.

If it was another user, maybe his/her `~/.bash_history` or similar file (for whichever shell the  user uses) may have that information, if they didn't delete it from there.

But actually, as other answers propose, there's no log. Just means of scanning the surface for removed files not-yet-overwritten.

By the way, using a Copy-on-write filesystem, such as ZFS or btrfs, you can track deleted files between "states" of the drive in time, called snapshots.

You can have a cron task run with the required time granularity to ensure there is a recent enough snapshot, and then diff between the snapshot and the current state.

There's another way.
You can compile your own rm binary, which **does** save traces of what did it do.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Unfortunately, there is no such log.  There are, however, several tools to *recover* deleted files.

Answer (score 0):

No. there is no such log. What is removed simply is removed.

If you have backups then you can compare the files in a backup with the files currently on the computer. That will give you a list of files removed in the time frame between the backup and now.